# How to select multiple picture from gallery using GMImagePicker in xamarin IOS?

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am following this [blog](https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/) for selecting multiple pictures from the gallery. For IOS I am Using `GMImagePicker` for selecting multiple pictures from the gallery.(In the blog suggesting elcimagepicker, but that is not available in Nuget Store now)

I go through the `GMImagePicker` [usage](https://github.com/roycornelissen/GMImagePicker.Xamarin#usage) part but didn't find how to add the selected images to `List` and pass that value in `MessagingCenter`(like the android implementation). In that usage part only telling about the picker settings. Anyone please give me any sample code for doing this feature?

Hi `Lucas Zhang - MSFT`, I tried your code but one question. Here you are passing only one file path through the `messagecenter`, so should I use a List for sending multiple file paths?

I am passing the picture paths as a `string List` from android. Please have a look at the android part code added below. Should I do like this in IOS?

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            List<string> images = new List<string>();

            if (data != null)
            {
                ClipData clipData = data.ClipData;
                if (clipData != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.ItemCount; i++)
                    {
                        ClipData.Item item = clipData.GetItemAt(i);
                        Android.Net.Uri uri = item.Uri;
                        var path = GetRealPathFromURI(uri);

                        if (path != null)
                        {
                            //Rotate Image
                            var imageRotated = ImageHelpers.RotateImage(path);
                            var newPath = ImageHelpers.SaveFile("TmpPictures", imageRotated, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"));
                            images.Add(newPath);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
                    var path = GetRealPathFromURI(uri);

                    if (path != null)
                    {
                        //Rotate Image
                        var imageRotated = ImageHelpers.RotateImage(path);
                        var newPath = ImageHelpers.SaveFile("TmpPictures", imageRotated, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"));
                        images.Add(newPath);
                    }
                }

                MessagingCenter.Send<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelected", images);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Also, I am getting an error, screenshot adding below:**

[image]

Comment: Update your forms to 3.x.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I will do that and update you

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I am working remotely in Mac, now I don't have mac access. When I get the Mac I will do the changes and update you.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT 
I have a small issue in the android part.

Picture extension(.jpg or .png) is not saving with the path for the android part. To upload the image to the server I need the complete image name with extension. So how can I save the complete name of the selected images with the extension? Can you please suggest any solution?

Comment: You can create a new question on so or forums so that we can help you better.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Started a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249377/xamarin-forms-picture-extension-is-not-saving-with-path-in-android-when-do-mult

Answer (score 0):

**GMImagePicker** will return a list contains `PHAsset` .So you could firstly get the filePath of the images and then pass them to forms by using `MessagingCenter` and `DependencyService`.Refer the following code.

> in Forms, create an interface

```
using System;

namespace app1
{
  public interface ISelectMultiImage
  {
    void SelectedImage();
  }
}
```

> in iOS project

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;
using GMImagePicker;
using Photos;
using Foundation;

[assembly:Dependency(typeof(SelectMultiImageImplementation))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class SelectMultiImageImplementation:ISelectMultiImage
  {
    public SelectMultiImageImplementation()
    {
    }


    string Save(UIImage image, string name)
    {
        var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath
                              (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, name); // hardcoded filename, overwritten each time
        NSData imgData = image.AsJPEG();
        if (imgData.Save(jpgFilename, false, out NSError err))
        {
            return jpgFilename;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT saved as " + jpgFilename + " because" + err.LocalizedDescription);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void SelectedImage()
    {

        var picker = new GMImagePickerController();
        picker.FinishedPickingAssets += (s, args) => {


            PHAsset[] assets = args.Assets;



            foreach (PHAsset asset in assets)
            {
                PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(asset, null, (NSData data, NSString dataUti, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary info) =>
                {
                    NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString(info.ValueForKey(new NSString("PHImageFileURLKey")).ToString());

                    string[] strs = url.Split("/");


                    UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);

                    string file = Save(UIImage.LoadFromData(data), strs[strs.Length - 1]);


                    MessagingCenter.Send<Object, string>(this, "ImagesSelected", file);

                }
                );

            }

        };
       UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(picker, true,null);

    }
  }
}
```

> in your contentPages

```
...
List<string> selectedImages;
...

public MyPage()
{
   selectedImages = new List<string>();
   InitializeComponent();

   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object,string>(this, "ImagesSelected",(object arg1,string arg2) =>
        {
            string source = arg2;

            selectedImages.Add(source);

        });

 }
```

If you want to select the images ,call the method

```
 DependencyService.Get<ISelectMultiImage>().SelectedImage();
```

Comment: hi I edited the question with a couple of questions, can you please look...

Comment: The name 'urlString' does not exist in the current context

Comment: string[] strs = urlString.Split("/");

Comment: Inside for each loop, can you please have a look?

Comment: Sorry , it is url.

Comment: I have answer your question on forums.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/149017/how-to-select-multiple-picture-from-galery-using-gmimagepicker-in-xamarin-ios?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186697/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672643/xamarin-forms-camera-picture-is-left-rotated-when-comes-to-ui-in-ios