# Xamarin forms: Picture extension is not saving with path in android when do multiple photo selection

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, path

I am following [this](https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/) article for **Select Multiple Images From Gallery in Xamarin Forms.**

I completed the feature in android part but the picture path contains only the picture name, extensions are missing when saving path.

To upload the image to the server I need the complete image name with extension. So how can I save the complete path of the selected images with the extension?

**Following method capture the image path:**

```
public String GetRealPathFromURI(Android.Net.Uri contentURI)
    {
        try
        {
            ICursor imageCursor = null;
            string fullPathToImage = "";

            imageCursor = ContentResolver.Query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            imageCursor.MoveToFirst();
            int idx = imageCursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);

            if (idx != -1)
            {
                fullPathToImage = imageCursor.GetString(idx);
            }
            else
            {
                ICursor cursor = null;
                var docID = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(contentURI);
                var id = docID.Split(':')[1];
                var whereSelect = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Id + "=?";
                var projections = new string[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };

                cursor = ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.InternalContentUri, projections, whereSelect, new string[] { id }, null);
                if (cursor.Count == 0)
                {
                    cursor = ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, projections, whereSelect, new string[] { id }, null);
                }
                var colData = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                fullPathToImage = cursor.GetString(colData);
            }
            return fullPathToImage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "Unable to get path", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension(.png or .jpg) was missing not from the `GetRealPathFromURI()`, it happens in `ImageHelpers.SaveFile()`. So I save the filename to another variable from the path using `Path.GetFileName()` like below and pass the complete filename when call `ImageHelpers.SaveFile()`.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(picturepath);
```