# Xamarin Forms: Camera picture is left rotated when comes to UI in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, rotation

The picture taken from the IOS camera is left rotated when showing it in the UI.

I already faced this type of issue and solved by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457482/xamarin-forms-jamesmontemagno-mediaplugin-selected-picture-is-rotating-when-ad). But in this case, I am saving only the `image path` to List.

Camera code:

```
public async void OpenMyCamera()
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> images = new List<string>();
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No camera available.", "Ok");
                    return;
                }

                _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Sample",
                    Name = "test.jpg",
                    AllowCropping = true
                });

                if (_mediaFile == null)
                    return;

                //Saving only the path to list.
                images.Add(_mediaFile.Path);

                MessagingCenter.Send<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelected", images);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
            }
        }
```

I am using `FlowListView` for showing the pictures using the following code.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelected", (s, images) =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
                    {
                        _images.Add(images[i]);
                        _images = new ObservableCollection<string>(_images.Distinct());
                        listItems.FlowItemsSource = _images;
                    }
                });
            }
```

What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: You should rotate the image yourself. If you pass the `imagepath` to the list, you have to rotate the image before the image has been set to its parent view(This means you need to change the source code of `FlowListView`).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT So before showing the image in flowlistview need to add rotation? I will try that, Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I will try it for you and let you know if I achieve it.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT ok, meanwhile I also try to find the solution.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Found image have `Rotation` property. But I have this problem only with ios camera. So how can I apply this to ios camera only?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I named image in xaml as `x:Name="upload_image"`, but in xaml.cs file it is not accessable?

Comment: 1. Try `if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)`.  2. Have you save your `xaml` file(Ctrl+s and try again)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188380/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-jack-hua-msft).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

**Update:**

This issue has been solved [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/365125#Comment_365125).

And there are also [discussions](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/334) on `MediaPlugin`'s GitHub

It seems this is a known issue when you set `AllowCropping` to true, check the image's `exif` data you will find the edited image has been rotated by 90 degrees. If you haven't used the image's `metadata`, try to close it to fix that:

```
var _mediaFile = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    Directory = "Sample",
    Name = "test.jpg",
    AllowCropping = true,
    SaveMetaData = false
});
```

**Previous answers**

Let's say you get a `MediaFile` after take photo:

```
MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });
```

Then transfer `MediaFile` into a `imageSource`:

Using `GetStreamWithImageRotatedForExternalStorage` will help you to solve the problem of 
 image is rotated  after taken photo in iOS.

```
ImageSource source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return file.GetStreamWithImageRotatedForExternalStorage();
            });
```

Then add this `source` to your `imageSource` list:

```
imageSourceList.Add(source);
```

Assume there is a model with one property source:

```
public class myModel
    {
        public ImageSource source { get; set; }
    }
```

At last, you can create a list of `myModel`, set the `images` as `FlowItemsSource`,  take as an example(assume there are 3 photos):

```
 var images = new List<myModel>();
 var a = new myModel {source = imageSourceList(0) };
 var b = new myModel {source = imageSourceList(1) };
 var c = new myModel {source = imageSourceList(2) };

 images.Add(a);
 images.Add(b);
 images.Add(c);

 myList.FlowItemsSource = images;
```

In the xaml, binding `soucre`:

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false" x:Name="myList">

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding source}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</flv:FlowListView>
```

Comment: GetStreamWithImageRotatedForExternalStorage() was the key for me